# Calculate grand total from span element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got changing Span value therefore I need get grand total for the span. I given the input fields a top level div id called **"sumDiv"** 
also my Span has "name" attribute as like this

```
var result = $("<span name='result'>");
```

the function to calculate all span is below:

```
function getDivSum(selector) {
          var sum = 0;
          $(selector).each(function() {
            $(this`enter code here`).children("span").each(function() {
              sum += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
          });
          return sum;
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
          console.log(getDivSum("#sumDiv"));
        });
```

**I am getting 0's for Grand total,
what I am doing wrong?**
this should get all span values

```
 $(this`enter code here`).children("span").each(function() {
```

but I am getting 0 value on console log.

also tried

```
$('.parent').each(function(){   
    var sum = 0;
    var counts = $(this).find('.count');

    counts.each(function() {
        sum+= parseInt($(this).text());
    });  
    console.log(sum);  
});
```

could not make it work.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/dunya/pen/MxXqrZ

**Thanks**

```js
function myLoad() {
        var apple   = 777777;
        var apricot   = 111111  ;
        var banana   = 222222  ;
        var bilberry   = 3333 ;
        var blackberry   = 3333  ;
        var blackcurrant   = 2222 ;
        var blueberry   = 88888 ;
        var boysenberry   = 8888888 ;
        var cherry   = 99999 ;
        var coconut = 99887 ;
    $("#Apple").value = apple;
    $("#Apricot").value = apricot;
    $("#Banana").value = banana;
    $("#Bilberry").value = bilberry;
    $("#Blackberry").value = blackberry;
    $("#Blackcurrant").value = blackcurrant;
    $("#Blueberry").value = blueberry;
    $("#Boysenberry").value = boysenberry;
    $("#Cherry").value = cherry;
    $("#Coconut").value = coconut;
}
function myCalculate(){
  var volume = $("#Volume").val();
  var productOrigin = $("#ProductOrigin").val();
  var geographicalLocation = $("#GeoLocation").val();
  
  if (volume === "" || productOrigin === "") {
  // alert("Please select the product origin and volume.");
  return;
 }
  
  var tableToUse = geographicalLocation === "" ? productOrigin : geographicalLocation;
  
  $("input[type='text']").each(function(i){
    
    // Current product ID, e.g. "Apple", "Apricot", etc.
   var currentProductId = $(this).attr('id');
    
    // Amount to multiply.
    var multiplier = $(`table#${tableToUse} tbody > tr[product='${currentProductId}'] > td[volume='${volume}']`).text();
    
    // A <span> element, to be populated with the calculated product volume.
 var result = $("<span name='result'>");

 // Calculate the figure and update the result element.
 result.text($(this).val() * multiplier); 

 // Remove any previously added <span> result elements.
 $(this).next("span").remove();

 // Insert result after the current input field.
 $(this).after(result);
    
   
    // to calculate Grand total
        function getDivSum(selector) {
          var sum = 0;
          $(selector).each(function() {
            $(this).children("span").each(function() {
              sum += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
          });
          return sum;
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
          console.log(getDivSum("#sumDiv"));
        });

  }); 
  
}



myLoad();

$('.select').on('change', myCalculate);
$("input[type='text']").on('keyup', myCalculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="ProductOrigin">Product Origin</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="ProductOrigin" name="ProductOrigin">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="description" for="GeoLocation">Geographical Location</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="GeoLocation" name="GeoLocation">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="England">England</option>
    <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
    <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Volume">Volume</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="Volume" name="Volume">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
    <option value="4000">4000</option>
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
    <option value="6000">6000</option>
    <option value="6000">6000</option>
    <option value="8000">8000</option>
    <option value="9000">9000</option>
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
    <option value="20000">20000</option>
    <option value="30000">30000</option>
    <option value="40000">40000</option>
    <option value="50000">50000</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="sumDiv">
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Apple">Apple</label>
  <input id="Apple" name="Apple" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Apricot">Apricot</label>
  <input id="Apricot" name="Apricot" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Banana">Banana</label>
  <input id="Banana" name="Banana" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Bilberry">Bilberry</label>
  <input id="Bilberry" name="Bilberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Blackberry">Blackberry</label>
  <input id="Blackberry" name="Blackberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Blackcurrant">Blackcurrant</label>
  <input id="Blackcurrant" name="Blackcurrant" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Blueberry">Blueberry</label>
  <input id="Blueberry" name="Blueberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Boysenberry">Boysenberry</label>
  <input id="Boysenberry" name="Boysenberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Cherry">Cherry</label>
  <input id="Cherry" name="Cherry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Coconut">Coconut</label>
  <input id="Coconut" name="Coconut" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>


<div>
  <label class="description" for="GrandTotal">Grand Total</label>
  <input id="GrandTotal" name="GrandTotal" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" readonly="true"/>
</div>

</div>

<table id="Europe">
  <thead>Europe</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Europe</td>
    <th id=10>10</th>
    <th id=100>100</th>
    <th id=1000>1000</th>
    <th id=2000>2000</th>
    <th id=3000>3000</th>
    <th id=4000>4000</th>
    <th id=5000>5000</th>
    <th id=6000>6000</th>
    <th id=7000>7000</th>
    <th id=8000>8000</th>
    <th id=9000>9000</th>
    <th id=10000>10000</th>
    <th id=20000>20000</th>
    <th id=30000>30000</th>
    <th id=40000>40000</th>
    <th id=50000>50000</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr product='Apple'>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>2</td>
      <td volume='3000'>3</td>
      <td volume='4000'>4</td>
      <td volume='5000'>5</td>
      <td volume='6000'>6</td>
      <td volume='7000'>7</td>
      <td volume='8000'>8</td>
      <td volume='9000'>9</td>
      <td volume='10000'>10</td>
      <td volume='20000'>11</td>
      <td volume='30000'>12</td>
      <td volume='40000'>13</td>
      <td volume='50000'>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Apricot'>
      <td>Apricot</td>
      <td volume='10'>0</td>
      <td volume='100'>0</td>
      <td volume='1000'>0</td>
      <td volume='2000'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>1</td>
      <td volume='4000'>1.5</td>
      <td volume='5000'>2</td>
      <td volume='6000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='7000'>3</td>
      <td volume='8000'>3.5</td>
      <td volume='9000'>4</td>
      <td volume='10000'>4.5</td>
      <td volume='20000'>5</td>
      <td volume='30000'>5.5</td>
      <td volume='40000'>6</td>
      <td volume='50000'>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Banana'>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>10</td>
      <td volume='4000'>15</td>
      <td volume='5000'>20</td>
      <td volume='6000'>25</td>
      <td volume='7000'>27</td>
      <td volume='8000'>30</td>
      <td volume='9000'>33</td>
      <td volume='10000'>36</td>
      <td volume='20000'>40</td>
      <td volume='30000'>45</td>
      <td volume='40000'>50</td>
      <td volume='50000'>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Bilberry'>
      <td>Bilberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>15</td>
      <td volume='3000'>20</td>
      <td volume='4000'>25</td>
      <td volume='5000'>30</td>
      <td volume='6000'>35</td>
      <td volume='7000'>40</td>
      <td volume='8000'>45</td>
      <td volume='9000'>50</td>
      <td volume='10000'>55</td>
      <td volume='20000'>60</td>
      <td volume='30000'>65</td>
      <td volume='40000'>70</td>
      <td volume='50000'>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blackberry'>
      <td>Blackberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>20</td>
      <td volume='3000'>50</td>
      <td volume='4000'>75</td>
      <td volume='5000'>100</td>
      <td volume='6000'>125</td>
      <td volume='7000'>150</td>
      <td volume='8000'>175</td>
      <td volume='9000'>200</td>
      <td volume='10000'>225</td>
      <td volume='20000'>250</td>
      <td volume='30000'>275</td>
      <td volume='40000'>300</td>
      <td volume='50000'>350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blackcurrant'>
      <td>Blackcurrant</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>2</td>
      <td volume='3000'>2</td>
      <td volume='4000'>4</td>
      <td volume='5000'>4</td>
      <td volume='6000'>4</td>
      <td volume='7000'>6</td>
      <td volume='8000'>6</td>
      <td volume='9000'>6</td>
      <td volume='10000'>8</td>
      <td volume='20000'>8</td>
      <td volume='30000'>10</td>
      <td volume='40000'>12</td>
      <td volume='50000'>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blueberry'>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>4</td>
      <td volume='3000'>6</td>
      <td volume='4000'>8</td>
      <td volume='5000'>10</td>
      <td volume='6000'>12</td>
      <td volume='7000'>14</td>
      <td volume='8000'>16</td>
      <td volume='9000'>18</td>
      <td volume='10000'>20</td>
      <td volume='20000'>24</td>
      <td volume='30000'>28</td>
      <td volume='40000'>30</td>
      <td volume='50000'>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Boysenberry'>
      <td>Boysenberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='100'>1</td>
      <td volume='1000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='2000'>4</td>
      <td volume='3000'>5.5</td>
      <td volume='4000'>7</td>
      <td volume='5000'>8.5</td>
      <td volume='6000'>10</td>
      <td volume='7000'>11.5</td>
      <td volume='8000'>13</td>
      <td volume='9000'>14.5</td>
      <td volume='10000'>16</td>
      <td volume='20000'>17.5</td>
      <td volume='30000'>19</td>
      <td volume='40000'>20.5</td>
      <td volume='50000'>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Cherry'>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='100'>1</td>
      <td volume='1000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='2000'>5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>8</td>
      <td volume='4000'>10</td>
      <td volume='5000'>15</td>
      <td volume='6000'>20</td>
      <td volume='7000'>25</td>
      <td volume='8000'>28</td>
      <td volume='9000'>31</td>
      <td volume='10000'>35</td>
      <td volume='20000'>40</td>
      <td volume='30000'>45</td>
      <td volume='40000'>50</td>
      <td volume='50000'>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Coconut'>
      <td>Coconut</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.25</td>
      <td volume='1000'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='2000'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>1</td>
      <td volume='4000'>1</td>
      <td volume='5000'>2</td>
      <td volume='6000'>2</td>
      <td volume='7000'>2</td>
      <td volume='8000'>2</td>
      <td volume='9000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='10000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='20000'>3</td>
      <td volume='30000'>3</td>
      <td volume='40000'>3</td>
      <td volume='50000'>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="England">
  <thead>England</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>England</td>
    <th id=10>10</th>
    <th id=100>100</th>
    <th id=1000>1000</th>
    <th id=2000>2000</th>
    <th id=3000>3000</th>
    <th id=4000>4000</th>
    <th id=5000>5000</th>
    <th id=6000>6000</th>
    <th id=7000>7000</th>
    <th id=8000>8000</th>
    <th id=9000>9000</th>
    <th id=10000>10000</th>
    <th id=20000>20000</th>
    <th id=30000>30000</th>
    <th id=40000>40000</th>
    <th id=50000>50000</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr product='Apple'>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td volume='10'>10</td>
      <td volume='100'>10</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>20</td>
      <td volume='3000'>30</td>
      <td volume='4000'>40</td>
      <td volume='5000'>50</td>
      <td volume='6000'>60</td>
      <td volume='7000'>70</td>
      <td volume='8000'>80</td>
      <td volume='9000'>90</td>
      <td volume='10000'>100</td>
      <td volume='20000'>110</td>
      <td volume='30000'>120</td>
      <td volume='40000'>130</td>
      <td volume='50000'>140</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Apricot'>
      <td>Apricot</td>
      <td volume='10'>10</td>
      <td volume='100'>10</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>20</td>
      <td volume='3000'>30</td>
      <td volume='4000'>40</td>
      <td volume='5000'>50</td>
      <td volume='6000'>60</td>
      <td volume='7000'>70</td>
      <td volume='8000'>80</td>
      <td volume='9000'>90</td>
      <td volume='10000'>100</td>
      <td volume='20000'>110</td>
      <td volume='30000'>120</td>
      <td volume='40000'>130</td>
      <td volume='50000'>140</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Banana'>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td volume='10'>1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>10</td>
      <td volume='4000'>15</td>
      <td volume='5000'>20</td>
      <td volume='6000'>25</td>
      <td volume='7000'>27</td>
      <td volume='8000'>30</td>
      <td volume='9000'>33</td>
      <td volume='10000'>36</td>
      <td volume='20000'>40</td>
      <td volume='30000'>45</td>
      <td volume='40000'>50</td>
      <td volume='50000'>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Bilberry'>
      <td>Bilberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>15</td>
      <td volume='3000'>20</td>
      <td volume='4000'>25</td>
      <td volume='5000'>30</td>
      <td volume='6000'>35</td>
      <td volume='7000'>40</td>
      <td volume='8000'>45</td>
      <td volume='9000'>50</td>
      <td volume='10000'>55</td>
      <td volume='20000'>60</td>
      <td volume='30000'>65</td>
      <td volume='40000'>70</td>
      <td volume='50000'>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blackberry'>
      <td>Blackberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>20</td>
      <td volume='3000'>50</td>
      <td volume='4000'>75</td>
      <td volume='5000'>100</td>
      <td volume='6000'>125</td>
      <td volume='7000'>150</td>
      <td volume='8000'>175</td>
      <td volume='9000'>200</td>
      <td volume='10000'>225</td>
      <td volume='20000'>250</td>
      <td volume='30000'>275</td>
      <td volume='40000'>300</td>
      <td volume='50000'>350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blackcurrant'>
      <td>Blackcurrant</td>
      <td volume='10'>20</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>2</td>
      <td volume='3000'>2</td>
      <td volume='4000'>4</td>
      <td volume='5000'>4</td>
      <td volume='6000'>4</td>
      <td volume='7000'>6</td>
      <td volume='8000'>6</td>
      <td volume='9000'>6</td>
      <td volume='10000'>8</td>
      <td volume='20000'>8</td>
      <td volume='30000'>10</td>
      <td volume='40000'>12</td>
      <td volume='50000'>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blueberry'>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>41</td>
      <td volume='100'>51</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>4</td>
      <td volume='3000'>6</td>
      <td volume='4000'>8</td>
      <td volume='5000'>10</td>
      <td volume='6000'>12</td>
      <td volume='7000'>14</td>
      <td volume='8000'>16</td>
      <td volume='9000'>18</td>
      <td volume='10000'>20</td>
      <td volume='20000'>24</td>
      <td volume='30000'>28</td>
      <td volume='40000'>30</td>
      <td volume='50000'>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Boysenberry'>
      <td>Boysenberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>500</td>
      <td volume='100'>10</td>
      <td volume='1000'>25</td>
      <td volume='2000'>4</td>
      <td volume='3000'>5</td>
      <td volume='4000'>7</td>
      <td volume='5000'>8</td>
      <td volume='6000'>10</td>
      <td volume='7000'>15</td>
      <td volume='8000'>13</td>
      <td volume='9000'>14</td>
      <td volume='10000'>16</td>
      <td volume='20000'>175</td>
      <td volume='30000'>19</td>
      <td volume='40000'>205</td>
      <td volume='50000'>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Cherry'>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='100'>1</td>
      <td volume='1000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='2000'>5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>8</td>
      <td volume='4000'>10</td>
      <td volume='5000'>15</td>
      <td volume='6000'>20</td>
      <td volume='7000'>25</td>
      <td volume='8000'>28</td>
      <td volume='9000'>31</td>
      <td volume='10000'>35</td>
      <td volume='20000'>40</td>
      <td volume='30000'>45</td>
      <td volume='40000'>50</td>
      <td volume='50000'>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Coconut'>
      <td>Coconut</td>
      <td volume='10'>41</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>115</td>
      <td volume='2000'>445</td>
      <td volume='3000'>1</td>
      <td volume='4000'>1</td>
      <td volume='5000'>2</td>
      <td volume='6000'>2</td>
      <td volume='7000'>2</td>
      <td volume='8000'>2</td>
      <td volume='9000'>2</td>
      <td volume='10000'>14</td>
      <td volume='20000'>3</td>
      <td volume='30000'>3</td>
      <td volume='40000'>3</td>
      <td volume='50000'>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="">
    <table id="multiplierSemtricaValues">
        <thead><strong>multiplierSemtricaValues</strong></thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>multiplierSemtricaValues</strong></td>
            <td id="">Value to apply</td> 
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr Semtrica='Apple'>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Apple'>65</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Apricot'>
                <td>Apricot</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Apricot'>141</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Banana'>
                <td>Banana</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Banana'>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Bilberry'>
                <td>Bilberry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Bilberry'>10.47</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Blackberry'>
                <td>Blackberry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Blackberry'>312</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Blackcurrant'>
                <td>Blackcurrant</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Blackcurrant'>292</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Blueberry'>
                <td>Blueberry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Blueberry'>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Boysenberry'>
                <td>Boysenberry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Boysenberry'>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Cherry'>
                <td>Cherry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Cherry'>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Cherry'>
                <td>Cherry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Cherry'>50</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you trim your code and keep the relevant parts please ?

Comment: For future reference - you put a lot of work into your question, but the result is TMI. I copied your code snippet into a new answer, to have a go at solving it, but I had no idea what to click, what to do to see the error. I suppose I could have spent half-an-hour or more trying to figure it out, but that's not how SO works. *Please create minimal, working, code examples* - trust me, the time you spend creating a demo for your question will save you twice as much in waiting for an answer - and you will sometimes find the answer for yourself while creating the question. Just my $0.02.

Comment: The issue with your console log is because you are calling this on doc ready and when doc is ready there is no value anywhere so you will get 0

Comment: @gibberish, yes you may be correct I might figure out, just want learn what is wrong with code, may be someone can help, I dont get your $0.02, is that the payment you receive from stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Codepen: https://codepen.io/dunya/pen/MxXqrZ
change this line

```
$(this).children("span").each(function() {
```

with this

```
$(this).children().children("span").each(function() {
```

Link to edited pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMjoXy

Comment: Your pen gives the same result as the OP

Comment: I have whire to change the line of code ed response with link to my pen.

Comment: @Scaff, the result is same as my pen.

Comment: @erkinddunya do you have see the console log? I have only update the value and not printed it

Comment: @scaff, thanks it works, on log it shows there.  Is there any way I can bind that result to input text box ID=GrandTotal.                                                                     <input id="GrandTotal" name="GrandTotal" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" readonly="true"/> ?

Comment: new question is added to explain my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241698/set-bind-input-values-using-span-values

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your console log is when you are logging this.

At document ready, there are no values or spans, so when you are trying to get the values, you are just going to get null values which converts to 0 and your result is 0.

When you are changing your inputs, the fields populate and your handler runs so you get the results beside the input boxes. Your original code uses `.children` on the `#sumDiv` but this won't work because the spans are not children of that div.

I changed that to

```
$(this).find("span").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).html());
});
```

Lastly, your grand total is 0, because that field has no value in it. So I just put together a simple line to update it

```
$("#GrandTotal").next().html(getDivSum("#sumDiv"))
```

A lot of things can be optimized I am sure but it is too much to go thru the entire thing. For one, you are running a loop thru every `#sumDiv` which should not be happening because IDs must be unique. If you have multiple of `#sumDiv`, you should use a class instead and loop thru the class

Here is the pen I created

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYZzEX

```js
function myLoad() {
        var apple   = 777777;
        var apricot   = 111111  ;
        var banana   = 222222  ;
        var bilberry   = 3333 ;
        var blackberry   = 3333  ;
        var blackcurrant   = 2222 ;
        var blueberry   = 88888 ;
        var boysenberry   = 8888888 ;
        var cherry   = 99999 ;
        var coconut = 99887 ;
    $("#Apple").value = apple;
    $("#Apricot").value = apricot;
    $("#Banana").value = banana;
    $("#Bilberry").value = bilberry;
    $("#Blackberry").value = blackberry;
    $("#Blackcurrant").value = blackcurrant;
    $("#Blueberry").value = blueberry;
    $("#Boysenberry").value = boysenberry;
    $("#Cherry").value = cherry;
    $("#Coconut").value = coconut;
}
function myCalculate(){
  var volume = $("#Volume").val();
  var productOrigin = $("#ProductOrigin").val();
  var geographicalLocation = $("#GeoLocation").val();
  
  if (volume === "" || productOrigin === "") {
  // alert("Please select the product origin and volume.");
  return;
 }
  
  var tableToUse = geographicalLocation === "" ? productOrigin : geographicalLocation;
  
  $("input[type='text']").each(function(i){
    
    // Current product ID, e.g. "Apple", "Apricot", etc.
   var currentProductId = $(this).attr('id');
    
    // Amount to multiply.
    var multiplier = $(`table#${tableToUse} tbody > tr[product='${currentProductId}'] > td[volume='${volume}']`).text();
    
    // A <span> element, to be populated with the calculated product volume.
 var result = $("<span name='result'>");

 // Calculate the figure and update the result element.
 result.text($(this).val() * multiplier); 

 // Remove any previously added <span> result elements.
 $(this).next("span").remove();

 // Insert result after the current input field.
 $(this).after(result);
    
   
    // to calculate Grand total
        function getDivSum(selector) {
          var sum = 0;
          $(selector).each(function() {
            $(this).find("span").each(function() {
              sum += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
          });
          return sum;
        }
    
    console.log(getDivSum("#sumDiv"))
    $("#GrandTotal").next().html(getDivSum("#sumDiv"))
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
          console.log(getDivSum("#sumDiv"));
        });

  }); 
  
}



myLoad();

$('.select').on('change', myCalculate);
$("input[type='text']").on('keyup', myCalculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="ProductOrigin">Product Origin</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="ProductOrigin" name="ProductOrigin">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="description" for="GeoLocation">Geographical Location</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="GeoLocation" name="GeoLocation">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="England">England</option>
    <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
    <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Volume">Volume</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="Volume" name="Volume">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
    <option value="4000">4000</option>
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
    <option value="6000">6000</option>
    <option value="6000">6000</option>
    <option value="8000">8000</option>
    <option value="9000">9000</option>
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
    <option value="20000">20000</option>
    <option value="30000">30000</option>
    <option value="40000">40000</option>
    <option value="50000">50000</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="sumDiv">
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Apple">Apple</label>
  <input id="Apple" name="Apple" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Apricot">Apricot</label>
  <input id="Apricot" name="Apricot" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Banana">Banana</label>
  <input id="Banana" name="Banana" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Bilberry">Bilberry</label>
  <input id="Bilberry" name="Bilberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Blackberry">Blackberry</label>
  <input id="Blackberry" name="Blackberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Blackcurrant">Blackcurrant</label>
  <input id="Blackcurrant" name="Blackcurrant" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Blueberry">Blueberry</label>
  <input id="Blueberry" name="Blueberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Boysenberry">Boysenberry</label>
  <input id="Boysenberry" name="Boysenberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Cherry">Cherry</label>
  <input id="Cherry" name="Cherry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Coconut">Coconut</label>
  <input id="Coconut" name="Coconut" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>


<div>
  <label class="description" for="GrandTotal">Grand Total</label>
  <input id="GrandTotal" name="GrandTotal" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" readonly="true"/>
</div>

</div>

<table id="Europe">
  <thead>Europe</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Europe</td>
    <th id=10>10</th>
    <th id=100>100</th>
    <th id=1000>1000</th>
    <th id=2000>2000</th>
    <th id=3000>3000</th>
    <th id=4000>4000</th>
    <th id=5000>5000</th>
    <th id=6000>6000</th>
    <th id=7000>7000</th>
    <th id=8000>8000</th>
    <th id=9000>9000</th>
    <th id=10000>10000</th>
    <th id=20000>20000</th>
    <th id=30000>30000</th>
    <th id=40000>40000</th>
    <th id=50000>50000</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr product='Apple'>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>2</td>
      <td volume='3000'>3</td>
      <td volume='4000'>4</td>
      <td volume='5000'>5</td>
      <td volume='6000'>6</td>
      <td volume='7000'>7</td>
      <td volume='8000'>8</td>
      <td volume='9000'>9</td>
      <td volume='10000'>10</td>
      <td volume='20000'>11</td>
      <td volume='30000'>12</td>
      <td volume='40000'>13</td>
      <td volume='50000'>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Apricot'>
      <td>Apricot</td>
      <td volume='10'>0</td>
      <td volume='100'>0</td>
      <td volume='1000'>0</td>
      <td volume='2000'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>1</td>
      <td volume='4000'>1.5</td>
      <td volume='5000'>2</td>
      <td volume='6000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='7000'>3</td>
      <td volume='8000'>3.5</td>
      <td volume='9000'>4</td>
      <td volume='10000'>4.5</td>
      <td volume='20000'>5</td>
      <td volume='30000'>5.5</td>
      <td volume='40000'>6</td>
      <td volume='50000'>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Banana'>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>10</td>
      <td volume='4000'>15</td>
      <td volume='5000'>20</td>
      <td volume='6000'>25</td>
      <td volume='7000'>27</td>
      <td volume='8000'>30</td>
      <td volume='9000'>33</td>
      <td volume='10000'>36</td>
      <td volume='20000'>40</td>
      <td volume='30000'>45</td>
      <td volume='40000'>50</td>
      <td volume='50000'>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Bilberry'>
      <td>Bilberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>15</td>
      <td volume='3000'>20</td>
      <td volume='4000'>25</td>
      <td volume='5000'>30</td>
      <td volume='6000'>35</td>
      <td volume='7000'>40</td>
      <td volume='8000'>45</td>
      <td volume='9000'>50</td>
      <td volume='10000'>55</td>
      <td volume='20000'>60</td>
      <td volume='30000'>65</td>
      <td volume='40000'>70</td>
      <td volume='50000'>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blackberry'>
      <td>Blackberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>20</td>
      <td volume='3000'>50</td>
      <td volume='4000'>75</td>
      <td volume='5000'>100</td>
      <td volume='6000'>125</td>
      <td volume='7000'>150</td>
      <td volume='8000'>175</td>
      <td volume='9000'>200</td>
      <td volume='10000'>225</td>
      <td volume='20000'>250</td>
      <td volume='30000'>275</td>
      <td volume='40000'>300</td>
      <td volume='50000'>350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blackcurrant'>
      <td>Blackcurrant</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>2</td>
      <td volume='3000'>2</td>
      <td volume='4000'>4</td>
      <td volume='5000'>4</td>
      <td volume='6000'>4</td>
      <td volume='7000'>6</td>
      <td volume='8000'>6</td>
      <td volume='9000'>6</td>
      <td volume='10000'>8</td>
      <td volume='20000'>8</td>
      <td volume='30000'>10</td>
      <td volume='40000'>12</td>
      <td volume='50000'>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blueberry'>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>4</td>
      <td volume='3000'>6</td>
      <td volume='4000'>8</td>
      <td volume='5000'>10</td>
      <td volume='6000'>12</td>
      <td volume='7000'>14</td>
      <td volume='8000'>16</td>
      <td volume='9000'>18</td>
      <td volume='10000'>20</td>
      <td volume='20000'>24</td>
      <td volume='30000'>28</td>
      <td volume='40000'>30</td>
      <td volume='50000'>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Boysenberry'>
      <td>Boysenberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='100'>1</td>
      <td volume='1000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='2000'>4</td>
      <td volume='3000'>5.5</td>
      <td volume='4000'>7</td>
      <td volume='5000'>8.5</td>
      <td volume='6000'>10</td>
      <td volume='7000'>11.5</td>
      <td volume='8000'>13</td>
      <td volume='9000'>14.5</td>
      <td volume='10000'>16</td>
      <td volume='20000'>17.5</td>
      <td volume='30000'>19</td>
      <td volume='40000'>20.5</td>
      <td volume='50000'>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Cherry'>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='100'>1</td>
      <td volume='1000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='2000'>5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>8</td>
      <td volume='4000'>10</td>
      <td volume='5000'>15</td>
      <td volume='6000'>20</td>
      <td volume='7000'>25</td>
      <td volume='8000'>28</td>
      <td volume='9000'>31</td>
      <td volume='10000'>35</td>
      <td volume='20000'>40</td>
      <td volume='30000'>45</td>
      <td volume='40000'>50</td>
      <td volume='50000'>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Coconut'>
      <td>Coconut</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.25</td>
      <td volume='1000'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='2000'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>1</td>
      <td volume='4000'>1</td>
      <td volume='5000'>2</td>
      <td volume='6000'>2</td>
      <td volume='7000'>2</td>
      <td volume='8000'>2</td>
      <td volume='9000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='10000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='20000'>3</td>
      <td volume='30000'>3</td>
      <td volume='40000'>3</td>
      <td volume='50000'>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="England">
  <thead>England</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>England</td>
    <th id=10>10</th>
    <th id=100>100</th>
    <th id=1000>1000</th>
    <th id=2000>2000</th>
    <th id=3000>3000</th>
    <th id=4000>4000</th>
    <th id=5000>5000</th>
    <th id=6000>6000</th>
    <th id=7000>7000</th>
    <th id=8000>8000</th>
    <th id=9000>9000</th>
    <th id=10000>10000</th>
    <th id=20000>20000</th>
    <th id=30000>30000</th>
    <th id=40000>40000</th>
    <th id=50000>50000</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr product='Apple'>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td volume='10'>10</td>
      <td volume='100'>10</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>20</td>
      <td volume='3000'>30</td>
      <td volume='4000'>40</td>
      <td volume='5000'>50</td>
      <td volume='6000'>60</td>
      <td volume='7000'>70</td>
      <td volume='8000'>80</td>
      <td volume='9000'>90</td>
      <td volume='10000'>100</td>
      <td volume='20000'>110</td>
      <td volume='30000'>120</td>
      <td volume='40000'>130</td>
      <td volume='50000'>140</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Apricot'>
      <td>Apricot</td>
      <td volume='10'>10</td>
      <td volume='100'>10</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>20</td>
      <td volume='3000'>30</td>
      <td volume='4000'>40</td>
      <td volume='5000'>50</td>
      <td volume='6000'>60</td>
      <td volume='7000'>70</td>
      <td volume='8000'>80</td>
      <td volume='9000'>90</td>
      <td volume='10000'>100</td>
      <td volume='20000'>110</td>
      <td volume='30000'>120</td>
      <td volume='40000'>130</td>
      <td volume='50000'>140</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Banana'>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td volume='10'>1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>10</td>
      <td volume='4000'>15</td>
      <td volume='5000'>20</td>
      <td volume='6000'>25</td>
      <td volume='7000'>27</td>
      <td volume='8000'>30</td>
      <td volume='9000'>33</td>
      <td volume='10000'>36</td>
      <td volume='20000'>40</td>
      <td volume='30000'>45</td>
      <td volume='40000'>50</td>
      <td volume='50000'>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Bilberry'>
      <td>Bilberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>15</td>
      <td volume='3000'>20</td>
      <td volume='4000'>25</td>
      <td volume='5000'>30</td>
      <td volume='6000'>35</td>
      <td volume='7000'>40</td>
      <td volume='8000'>45</td>
      <td volume='9000'>50</td>
      <td volume='10000'>55</td>
      <td volume='20000'>60</td>
      <td volume='30000'>65</td>
      <td volume='40000'>70</td>
      <td volume='50000'>75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blackberry'>
      <td>Blackberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>10</td>
      <td volume='2000'>20</td>
      <td volume='3000'>50</td>
      <td volume='4000'>75</td>
      <td volume='5000'>100</td>
      <td volume='6000'>125</td>
      <td volume='7000'>150</td>
      <td volume='8000'>175</td>
      <td volume='9000'>200</td>
      <td volume='10000'>225</td>
      <td volume='20000'>250</td>
      <td volume='30000'>275</td>
      <td volume='40000'>300</td>
      <td volume='50000'>350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blackcurrant'>
      <td>Blackcurrant</td>
      <td volume='10'>20</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>2</td>
      <td volume='3000'>2</td>
      <td volume='4000'>4</td>
      <td volume='5000'>4</td>
      <td volume='6000'>4</td>
      <td volume='7000'>6</td>
      <td volume='8000'>6</td>
      <td volume='9000'>6</td>
      <td volume='10000'>8</td>
      <td volume='20000'>8</td>
      <td volume='30000'>10</td>
      <td volume='40000'>12</td>
      <td volume='50000'>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Blueberry'>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>41</td>
      <td volume='100'>51</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
      <td volume='2000'>4</td>
      <td volume='3000'>6</td>
      <td volume='4000'>8</td>
      <td volume='5000'>10</td>
      <td volume='6000'>12</td>
      <td volume='7000'>14</td>
      <td volume='8000'>16</td>
      <td volume='9000'>18</td>
      <td volume='10000'>20</td>
      <td volume='20000'>24</td>
      <td volume='30000'>28</td>
      <td volume='40000'>30</td>
      <td volume='50000'>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Boysenberry'>
      <td>Boysenberry</td>
      <td volume='10'>500</td>
      <td volume='100'>10</td>
      <td volume='1000'>25</td>
      <td volume='2000'>4</td>
      <td volume='3000'>5</td>
      <td volume='4000'>7</td>
      <td volume='5000'>8</td>
      <td volume='6000'>10</td>
      <td volume='7000'>15</td>
      <td volume='8000'>13</td>
      <td volume='9000'>14</td>
      <td volume='10000'>16</td>
      <td volume='20000'>175</td>
      <td volume='30000'>19</td>
      <td volume='40000'>205</td>
      <td volume='50000'>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Cherry'>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='100'>1</td>
      <td volume='1000'>2.5</td>
      <td volume='2000'>5</td>
      <td volume='3000'>8</td>
      <td volume='4000'>10</td>
      <td volume='5000'>15</td>
      <td volume='6000'>20</td>
      <td volume='7000'>25</td>
      <td volume='8000'>28</td>
      <td volume='9000'>31</td>
      <td volume='10000'>35</td>
      <td volume='20000'>40</td>
      <td volume='30000'>45</td>
      <td volume='40000'>50</td>
      <td volume='50000'>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Coconut'>
      <td>Coconut</td>
      <td volume='10'>41</td>
      <td volume='100'>5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>115</td>
      <td volume='2000'>445</td>
      <td volume='3000'>1</td>
      <td volume='4000'>1</td>
      <td volume='5000'>2</td>
      <td volume='6000'>2</td>
      <td volume='7000'>2</td>
      <td volume='8000'>2</td>
      <td volume='9000'>2</td>
      <td volume='10000'>14</td>
      <td volume='20000'>3</td>
      <td volume='30000'>3</td>
      <td volume='40000'>3</td>
      <td volume='50000'>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="">
    <table id="multiplierSemtricaValues">
        <thead><strong>multiplierSemtricaValues</strong></thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>multiplierSemtricaValues</strong></td>
            <td id="">Value to apply</td> 
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr Semtrica='Apple'>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Apple'>65</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Apricot'>
                <td>Apricot</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Apricot'>141</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Banana'>
                <td>Banana</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Banana'>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Bilberry'>
                <td>Bilberry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Bilberry'>10.47</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Blackberry'>
                <td>Blackberry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Blackberry'>312</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Blackcurrant'>
                <td>Blackcurrant</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Blackcurrant'>292</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Blueberry'>
                <td>Blueberry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Blueberry'>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Boysenberry'>
                <td>Boysenberry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Boysenberry'>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Cherry'>
                <td>Cherry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Cherry'>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr Semtrica='Cherry'>
                <td>Cherry</td>
                <td valueToCalc='Cherry'>50</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can overwrite the input box with calculated SPAN values and for the final SPAN result to write to input (ID=GrandTotal), many thanks sorry to consume your time. many thanks in advance

Comment: new question is added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241698/set-bind-input-values-using-span-values

Comment: Yes there is, I am sure someone will answer your other question