# Set/bind input values using SPAN values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working Code-pen, the calculated results are showing on next to input fields SPAN. I tried to get that calculated value from SPAN and overwrite the input fields.

```
 <!-- Include this line of code --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtx1" /><br />
<span id="txtSpan"></span>
<input type="button" value="Appended-textBox" id="Btn3" />
```

**and the JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#Btn3').click(function() {
        var txtvalue = $('#txtx1').val();
        $("#txtSpan").text(txtvalue);
        console.log(txtvalue);
      });
    });
```

**The above works I just want to other way around setting the Input with changing SPAN value.**

Is there any way I can overwrite the input box with calculated SPAN values and for the final SPAN result to write to input (ID=GrandTotal),

```
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Coconut">Coconut</label>
  <input id="Coconut" name="Coconut" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>


<div>
  <label class="description" for="GrandTotal">Grand Total</label>
  <input id="GrandTotal" name="GrandTotal" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" readonly="true"/>
</div>
```

**Many thanks and sorry to consume your time. many thanks in advance**

**https://codepen.io/dunya/pen/mojKNz**

Comment: You can extract the span text with `var textvalue = $("#txtSpan").text();` and put it in the input with `$('#txtx1').val(textvalue);`. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: thanks it guided me to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding below line:please check the working version above pen.

```
$('#GrandTotal').val(parseInt($(this).html()));
```

when I tried the

```
$('#GrandTotal').val(sum);
```

it gave me the wrong calculation.